# How to stop the 'Invalid name' error on Minecraft: Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Every time I try and connect to my brother or cousins game it says Invalid Name. I have been playing Minecraft for a very long time and since this new update It loads for about one second then it says "Invalid Name!"

Answer (score -1):

Change your name or ask them to change theirs? Maybe they are older names, or you have an older name. Try those, and if they work, (i hope they do!) Then you should try a few times and keep checking.

Comment: Thank you DivaGirllsChic. If anybody is having trouble change your server name so that it doesn't have any spaces or special characters. This helped for mea and I hope this works for you.